# UISearchBar inside UIView where search is working but scroll and select is not

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a custom `UISearchBar` using `UIView`. Searching is working perfectly but `UITableView` scrolling and selecting is not working. I have attached my sample project here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ZOj-3b5Sx4cF82VTU4M0F1dW8/view

Comment: You should describe your problem, not only what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need to use searchbar in all viewcontroller. No need to create again and again search bar and tableview in all viewcontroller that's y i was create custom search bar. Here search is working but tableview scrolling is not working. Sorry for english.

Comment: Yes, but you should try to implement yourself and then post your code when you have a problem you can't solve. If you don't know how to create custom views in general read the view controller programming guide from apple. Or search for tutorials online. You won't get a complete implementation here at stackoverflow.

Comment: No I almost did check my code tableview scrolling only not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it:

You put the tableView outside the frame ... it is visible, but not on the frame of your search view, so it is NOT tappable.

I changed some lines and it worked:

```
searchTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 51.0);
searchTextField.delegate = self;
searchTextField.showsBookmarkButton = YES;
[self addSubview:searchTextField];

CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, searchTextField.frame.origin.y+self.searchTextField.frame.size.height, 320, 200);

tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:fr style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Notice the fixed height of 51.0 for the searchbar and the changed calculation of the tableView frame. AND you have to set the height of the searchView to 251 in the ViewController.xib.